# Storing functions in MongoDB in different collections?

Tags: mongodb

Say that I have a business that represents `users` who spend a certain amount of `time` to produce certain `quantities` of stuff. I want each user to be free to create their own algorithm, or formula, for determining the price that they charge for their work:

`Users Collection`, with possibly thousands of different users.

```
{
  userId: 'sdf23d23dwew',
  price: function(time, qty){
    // some algorithm
  }
},
{
  userId: '23f5gf34f',
  price: function(time, qty){
    // another algorithm
  }
},
{
  userId: '7u76565',
  price: function(time, qty){
    // yet another algorithm
  }
},
{
  userId: 'w45y65yh4',
  price: function(time, qty){
    // something else
  }
}

//and on and on and on...
```

Now, `JSON` doesn't support functions and neither does `MongoDB`. BUT this use-case of possibly thousands of users, each with the freedom to create their own unique method of determining their own prices, seems to me like being able to store functions inside of their user document would be ideal.

I certainly don't feel like it's a good idea to just store all these thousands of functions in a `JS` file on the server that somehow gets referenced by a `userId` when it's needed...

Is there a solution for this case?

Comment: MongoDB **does** support storing "code" because it is in fact a BSON type. e.g `db.func.insert({ "a": function() { return "Hello" } })` and then anything that supports [extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) such as mongoexport, i.e `mongoexport -d test -c func` produces `{"_id":{"$oid":"5705e54abde65de1739a8d2a"},"a":{"$code":"function () { return \"hello\" }"}}`. But I really don't see the point of where you think you are going to use this. You probably should be doing this as you inflate the objects instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "inflate" the object?

Comment: What I mean is understanding the distinction between whether you "really need" a separate function stored on each object, **or** whether each object is in fact a "class" for which depending on the data it has can instantiate an object of it's "type" that already has the standard methods attached. The problem here is that your question is "too vague" and you really don't describe your intent of storing these functions in the first place **or** how they need to be used later. But as noted, your conclusions are incorrect as you can both "store" and "transport" the data portably.

Comment: There are no standard methods. That's the point. Every user in the DB is able to create a completely unique formula for calculating their final price. The formula needs to be attached onto their user document that's stored in Mongo. The intention and usage is obvious - query the user object and then run the `price` function that's stored on it to return that user's price. Imagine seeing a list of all the users in the system and all their individual prices generated via their unique formulas and displayed on the page.

Comment: All I see in your comment is the ability to store a function as a string. And then what? Use `eval`, which is slow?

Comment: If you are actually using a server side JavaScript engine such as `nodejs`, then the "driver" will automatically make that code reference an actual `function()` as a property of the retrieved object. In other languages it will be a special object of `MongoCode` or similar name. If you sent content to a "browser" then yes you would `eval()` the content back into the object property ( which is probably exactly what the driver is doing ). Your question and short responses are still really unclear. If you took the time to explain your usage then perhaps a more meaningful answer would explain.

Comment: This response is what I was looking for. I'll store the functions in MongoDB and execute them on the server and return the results (`price`) back to the client.

Comment: Hey @fuzzybabybunny were you successful with this approach? I have a similar requirement, and I'd like some confirmation before I start writing code